# Dirac delta function and Kronecker delta function

Tags: definition, notation, dirac-delta-distributions

Can someone please tell me the difference between [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) and [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)?

Comment: Discrete versus continuous arguments. Go to Wikipedia and read up. May delete question.

Comment: [Maybe this helps?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Relationship_to_the_Dirac_delta_function)

Comment: Hi Mencur Emraan, Welcome to Phys.SE. Note that one is expected to do some basic research (e.g. looking up the the relevant Wikipedia pages) before asking.

Answer (score 6):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

**Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$**: Takes as input (usually in QM) two integers $i$ and $j$, and spits out 1 if they're the same and 0 if they're different. Notice that $i$ and $j$ are *integers* as such are in a *discrete* space.

**Dirac delta distribution $\delta(x)$**: Takes as input a real number $x$, "spits out infinity" if $x=0$, otherwise outputs 0.

You can see it as if the delta distribution/function is the *continuous variant* of the Kronecker delta, but don't take it too far as it breaks down once it's out of an integral.

Comment: Thank you so very much